# Link podfile with multiple projects

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have at least two xcodeproj in my workspace RTComponents

- RTComponents

  - RTCore
  - RTExtension

I would like to add a Pods project to get this straight forward hierarchy:

- RTComponents

  - RTCore
  - RTExtension
  - Pods

Both projects RTCore and RTExtension should be able to utilize all frameworks brought with the Pods project.

I have the following Podfile (which unfortunately ignores RTCore):

```
workspace 'RTComponents.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, "6.0"

xcodeproj 'RTCore/RTCore.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'RTExtension/RTExtension.xcodeproj'

link_with ['RTCore', 'RTExtension']

pod 'RestKit'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK'
```

I tried various configurations but cocoapods just doesn't want to introduce himself to RTCore.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I switch the order of the project and target declarations, the libPod gets linked with RTCore! This seems like a bug to me, but I am still not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: Does RTExtension utilize something from RTCore? If so, have you considered making a pod from RTCore?